# Обезьяна — опица

Tags: этимология

Слово "обезьяна" тут уже обсуждалось — пришли к выводу, что это персидское слово. Но вот интернет дает еще одно уточнение: старое русское название обезьяны — *опица*. И вот, мне стало интересно, что это за слово, что оно означает? А еще: как вообще в русском языке взялось какое-то название для животного, которое на Руси и в близлежащих территориях никогда не водилось?
В общем, кто такая *опица*?

Comment: Что такое "интернет даёт"? Кто конкретно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно предположить, что слово ***"опица"*** и англ. слово ***"ape"*** (обезьяна) имеют общие корни.

Старо-английское и шведское *apa*, исландское *api*. Когда-то через Киев шёл путь из варяг в греки. Может быть тогда от северных германцев славяне это слово и позаимствовали.

Плюс суффикс -ица. Апа - апица. Похоже на другое название животного времен Киевской Руси: куна - куница.

Конечно можно было бы предположить и обратное. Допустим, что здесь праиндоевропейский корень, суффикс -ица тоже очень древний. Т.е. допустим, что **у нас**, славян, более древний вариант. А германцы по своему обыкновению слово упростили, сократили. И звук "о" изменили на "а" -- аналогично праславянское "горъд-" (что-то огороженое: гОрод, огорОд) и древнегерманское "gard-" (garden).НО! Обезьян в наших краях вроде бы никогда не бывало.

Так что всё же предполагаю, что завезли славянам диковинного нездешнего зверька под названием **"апа"** купцы заморские.

Это слово в других славянских языках: сербо-хорв. *опица*, словен. *oрiса*, чеш. *орiсе*, др.-польск. *орiса* (ХV в.), в.-луж. *wорiса*, полаб. оро́. Обратите внимание на последний, полабский, вариант. Тут ещё раз задумаешься: кто у кого позаимствовал.

Comment: "Праславянское", "праиндоевропейский" это кто, что? Русское -город- от "гарда"- охрана, защита.
Рось называли Гардарикой. Слово известно со времен Мидии.  
И у кого это "у нас славян"? Кто вы сегодня?
Древнегерманское "gard-" это "garda" даичей. А это не одно и то же.

Comment: Дополню . "Полный церковно-славянский словарь" под редакцией Г.Дьяченко даёт ещё одно обозначение обезьяны - ПIФИКЪ = ПИФИК . Интернет-ссылка : http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_1082.htm . Смотреть в "Прибавлениях" по букве П . Этот же словарь приводит и слово ОПИЦА с тем же значением - обезьяна . http://www.slavdict.narod.ru/_0384.htm

Answer (score 0):

опица  идет  от Api - пчела В латыни.  Пчелы живут семьями. 
Обезьяна. Они тоже живут семьями.
в датском очень близко к нашему –abe,  в голландском—aap  в исландском –api, в английском ape     совпадением это быть не может.
В латыни обезьяна -- simia  -  русское, семья

Семья. Семья--это обуза.
Обезьяна имеет в английском синоним monkey.   Явно два корня    монета—ключ.  За деньги и запереть. Обезьян возили в клетке и показывали за деньги.
Почему так?  В малайском осталась причина, обезьяна---monyet,  старинное испанское moneda  монета.
В боснийском,  албанском, македонском, турецком, и еще нескольких  обезьяна- majmun,   по корням maj   --может   mun—искаженное man - человек.   Логика. Почти человек. И там в языках, где такой корень или похожий, то же самое.

И все таки  наше слово обезьяна идет от обузы,   в греческом обуза-- επιβάρυνση epivárynsi̱, в африкаанс обуза – beswaring, от голландского.
А что видим в корнях---пчела и забота, то бишь  ОБУЗА. Почему обуза?
Потому как  семью в обозе возили, в том числе и пасеку тоже.
То есть обуза от обоза.

обоз обо́з род. п. -а, укр. обíз, род. п. обо́зу, цслав. обозъ, чеш. оbоz "поклажа, ограждение из телег", польск. оbо́z, род. п. оbоzu "лагерь". Из *оb-vоzъ, см. воз, везу́. Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973

Это не ограждение, это просто куча телег друг за другом на дороге. Это то, что медленно тащится, тормоз, обуза, обязанность и обязательства. Там семьи, скарб, запасы и все это надо защищать, заботиться, выполнять обязанности по отношению к этому дому на колесах. Можно встать лагерем в круг и получается импровизированная крепость.  Можно и сделать гуляй-город.  ГуляйПоль, Вагенбург.
Вот тут и подоспеют скоропалительные Фасмеры с ираноосетинским прогерманским исключительно правым И.Е. мнением. И скажут, что обоз от воза пошел.
а то что в обозе возят  это только в современной грамматике обозный,а не обвозный
обiз--яный  никак быть не могло? не должно?
совсем не обезьятельно!!!!!!!

бегемот, говорят--еврейское. 
10. По мнению Делича, Ланге и др. , "бегемот" - гебраизированное коптско-египетское слово "p-ehe-mau" (р = определенный член; еhе - бык; mau = вода) , - водяной бык, гиппопотам. LXX поняли "бегемот" в смысле множественного числа от слова "бегема" - животное, откуда и их чтение: qhria - звери. Древние экзегеты разумели под "бегемот" слона, но некоторые подробности в описании данного животного (ст. 11) не приложимы к последнему. Созданный так же хорошо, как и человек ("создал, как и тебя"), бегемот принадлежит к разряду травоядных животных, но резко выделяется из их среды своею силою.

Что интересно, в коптском бык по-другому и вода тоже. А с египетским проблемно, там вообще гласных нет.
Называется такая этимология дурдомом от фонаря.

Для этого надо со словарями потрудиться, а лениво, таким как вы, проще поерничать. Так напороться проблем нет, потому как по верхам бегаете и компиляторством занимаетесь, как Фасмеры.
Так что поле чудес в языковедении от корней, произношения дурного и смешения азбук—латинской и «кириллицы», ну а дальше тупые МОНКИ потрудились.

А еще это hippo   как никак лошадь с древнегреческого, интересно, вам в голову не приходило, что бегемот быстрее лошади бегает, когда ему надо. Лошадь потом потом исходит, чтоб догнать.. Ударение.
А каков смысл! А еще это парнокопытное!  Классификация  аж 17 века.
А еще это нильская лошадь  nijlpaard
virtahevon -- сильная лошадь-финский
flodnest -- водяная лошадь. датский

В латыни есть нечто похожее на воду с корнем pota, напиток
potabilis, e [poto] годный для питья (medicamina 
СА); содержащий питьевую воду (fons Amm). Но не вода.
Русский «пот» ничего не напоминает?

результат--гиппопотам.

смотрим у фасмера:
бегемот бегемо́т "гиппопотам", нем., лат. Behemoth, из др.-евр. behemoth, собственно мн. – библейское название самого большого сухопутного животного, вероятно, гиппопотама; см. Хайзе; Маценауэр 108.

ну да, слова рот - mouth и bag –чемодан. 
Результат—бегемот. Выходит что даже не немецкий.
 А как же, евреи кругом одни евреи, английские, немецкие, польские, древнееврейский сочинили, вопрос-когда?

То же самое и с вашим монахом--монк, вы забываете, что это общепринятое сокращение, а не исходное от  mono-один.
И практически в каждом языке есть полное наименование,  да еще и свое собственное, кроме греколатинского, да еще с кучей синонимов.

Comment: Обезьяны в славянских землях никогда не водились . Вероятность того , что на Руси сами могли придумать им название ничтожна . Информация об этом звере усваивалась  вместе с иноземными его названиями . Может быть , по-вашему , и БЕГЕМОТ это тот , кто БЕГАЕТ И МОТАЕТ ГОЛОВОЙ ? И ещё один вопросик ,- я не берусь опровергать вашу англоязычную версию . а просто интересуюсь : monkey = mon(ey)+key , но есть , ведь , и англ. слово monk - монах , - не может ли в их робингудовском понимании обезьяна быть тем , что похоже на монаха ? Пожалуйста ,  отразите и этот момент , только не перегрейтесь мозгами 

Comment: Следопыт!,  здесь развернуто не влезает, так что смотрите основной текст...
Что касается похожести обезьяны на монаха--так то точно так. И те и те нахлебники, их в обозе возили, обуза.

Comment: @fatyalink . Мой предыдущий комент повлек новый мощный словесный понос с Вашей стороны . Вы не уловили моей иронии . Результат оказался прямо противоположным ожидаемому .

Comment: Так все правильно, в средней полосе России от Днепра до Волги не водились, зато наши везде побывали, эта история официальная уже достала, типа  Афанасия Никитина, первого купца российского, типа вообще за кордоном первого, и типа  жены короля французского, тоже первой, дочери Ярослава. Говорят, "язык до Киева доведет".  Вот в языках то история и спрятана.
А анализ показывает комплексный, что  не все так просто, и арабский язык, просто к примеру--хранит массу русских корней, не по ИЕ технологии, как впрочем и все европейские и др.

Comment: зебра по арабски-точно-забор. жирафа - искаженный журавль, на первых русских пушках арабская вязь,арабские монеты в кладах, а может а раб, не араб, а работник? прозвище Авицены- от пчелы и цены на мед, а медицина от меда и цены.
а может о датировках поговорим и сказках от дендрологии? и физики с которой проблемно все от квантовой механики.
 порох не китайский, мушкеты не французские, вот это и выяснятся.
так что про обезьян и их пребывание на нашей территории, извините, судя по языкам, территория была очень большая.

Answer (score 0):

о́пица

"обезьяна", только русск.-цслав. опица (Григ. Наз., Ио. Экзарх и др.), сербохорв. о̏пица, словен. о̑рiса, чеш. орiсе, др.-польск. орiса (ХV в.), в.-луж. wорiса, полаб. оро́.

Заимств. в форме *оръ из д.-в.-н. affo "обезьяна", др.-исл. арi, откуда* орiса но аналогии волк : волчица и под.; см. Шварц, AfslPh 41, 125; Уленбек, AfslPh 15, 489; Стендер-Петерсен 359 и сл.; Кипарский 251 и сл. Несостоятельны сомнения в герм. происхождении у Торпа (14). Праслав. древность тоже невероятна, как и заимствование русск. слова из др.-сканд.

(Фасмер)

Answer (score 0):

Архаичное слово «опица» - обезьяна вероятнее всего происходит от того же корня, что и слово «вопить». Потревоженная стая обезьян производит столько крика, что трудно представить для этого животного более точное прозвище, чем «крикливая» или «вопящая».
О позднем присоединении буквы «в» к основе слова «вопить» упоминается в эт. словаре Крылова Г.А.: «Вопи́ть. Общеславянское образование ъпъ при появлении начального в».
Конечное «…ица» характерно для образования слов в нашем языке: куна - куница, пъта – птица, горло - горлица, живо – живица, зиять – зеница, пение – певец / певица, тупо - тупица и пр.
В наше время обезьяну называют словом «opice» в чешском, словенском, словацком языках.
О том, что славяне - путешественники (купцы, миссионеры) в самые давние времена достигали зоны тропических лесов косвенно свидетельствуют такие слова как «пальма», «опица» и не только:  https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/k-etimologii-nazvaniy-nekotoryh-predstaviteley-afrikanskoy-fauny